# Compact operators evaluated on the sequence of eigenvalues

Tags: convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, compactness, compact-operators

Let $A: H\to H$ and $B: H\to H$ be two compact operators defined on a Hilbert space $H$.
Let $(x_n)$ the sequence of eigenfunctions of $A$.

Since $B$ is compact and $(x_n)$ is a basis for $H$ then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \langle B(x_n),x_n\rangle=0
$$
It is possible to prove that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\langle A(x_n),x_n\rangle}{\langle B(x_n),x_n\rangle}=0
$$
?

Some adds: $A\neq B$, $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint positive definite, furthermore $\mathcal{R}(A) \bigcap \mathcal{R}(B)= (0)$

Comment: As $A$ and $B$ are generic me may take  $A=B$ as a counterexample.

Comment: I've just added some details to the question

Comment: You should at least assume that $\langle Bx, x \rangle >0$ for all x \neq 0$ so that your ratio is defined.

Comment: Yes, $B$ is a positive definite compact operator

Comment: Probably not. If $a_n\rightarrow 0$ then it necessitates that $\frac{1}{a_n}$ does not converge to zero. This means that if it holds for some $A,B$ then once you interchange their roles it will not longer hold. In other words, any example will generate a counterexample. Edit: I just gave an example below.

Comment: I think you should put this comment as an answer

Comment: The main point is that the ranges of $A$ and $B$ have only trivial intersection, but I can't figure out how to exploit this to prove the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Look at $H=l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $x_n=e_n$ are the unit vectors.

Let $A$ be the unique operator defined by $Ae_n = \frac{1}{n} e_{n}$ when $n$ is odd and zero otherwise, let $B$ be the unique operator defined by $Be_n = \frac{1}{n^2}(e_{2n} + e_n)$ when $n$ is odd and $B_{e_n} = \frac{1}{n^2}e_{2n}$ when $n$ is even.

Then for odd $n$'s we have $\frac{\left<Ae_n,e_n\right>}{\left<Be_n,e_n\right>} = n$ and therefore the limit as $n$ goes to infinity does not exists.

On the other hand, the range of $A$ is $l^2(2\mathbb{N}+1)$ (i.e. sequences $a_n\in l^2(\mathbb{N})$ for which $a_{2n}=0$ for all $n$). The image of $l^2(2\mathbb{N})$ under $B$ is $l^2(4\mathbb{N})$ and the image of $l^2(2\mathbb{N}+1)$ under $B$ does not intersect with $l^2(4\mathbb{N})\oplus l^2(2\mathbb{N}+1)$. Therefore the range of $B$ does not intersect with the range of $A$.

Comment: I think this example contradicts my hypothesis since the ranges of A and B must have only trivial intersection

Comment: @Vinz fixed that

Comment: Maybe it is a stupid question, forgive me if that's the case. If we consider $H=L^2(\partial\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ a bounded domain of $R^n$, $n\geq 2$ so both $\mathcal{R}(A)$ and $\mathcal{R}(B)$ are dense subsets of $H$ and $\mathcal{R}(A^{1/2})\cap\mathcal{R}(B^{1/2})=\{0\}$, is it still possible to find a counterexample?

Comment: @Vinz what do you mean by $A^{1/2}$?

Comment: The square root of the compact operator $A$

Comment: Oh sorry, did not see they're positive definite. Ok the fact that $\partial \Omega$ is compact make things a bit different. I'll think about it, though perhaps you'll get more attention from other users by posting this as a separate question.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to write a new question.